# angular 2 (click) on component tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two `angular` components. The first component is a list with the tag `<my-list-comp></my-list-comp>`. My second component is a button with the tag `<my-button-comp></my-button-comp>`. In the template of my list component I'm using the button component with it's tag like this:

template `my-list-comp.html`:

```
<div class="list>
    <ul><!-- some stuff --></ul>
    <my-button-comp></my-button-comp>
</div>
```

template `my-button-comp.html`:

```
<button routerLink="/goToOtherComponent">Click me!</button>
```

Now my question: Is it possible to use the `(click)` on the tag `<my-button-comp></my-button-comp>` to call a `function` from the `controller` in `my-list-comp` like this:

template `my-list-comp.html`:

```
<div class="list>
    <ul><!-- some stuff --></ul>
    <my-button-comp (click)="myFunction()"></my-button-comp>
</div>
```

controller `my-list.comp.ts`:

```
myFunction() {
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

I've tried it like above, but it didn't work? Is this possible? Didn't find anything about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use an EventEmitter and the Output decorator like so:

**my-button-comp.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() onBtnClick = new EventEmitter<undefined>();
```

**my-button-comp.html**

```
<button (click)="onBtnClick.emit()">Click me!</button>
```

**my-list-comp.html**

```
<div class="list>
    <ul><!-- some stuff --></ul>
    <my-button-comp (onBtnClick)="myFunction()"></my-button-comp>
</div>
```

Comment: Another question: If there is also a routerLink on the button in the my-button-comp so when I click it goes to another route and should call myFunction() it seems not to work. How to solve this? Any ideas -> I edited the question take a look at my-button-template

Comment: You should ask another question, but the answer would be to inject 'Router" in your constructor and use the navigate or navigateByURL functions.

Answer (score 0):

With angular components, the `(something)` syntax refers to events from a child to a parent component (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) for the official docs) so what you are doing is invalid.

If you want to trigger something from a child to a parent, the correct way of doing it is to send an event from the child and have the proper listener in place in the parent component.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the right way to call a function in the list controller when clicking on the button in the button component? So I have to put the (click) on the button tag in the template of my-button-comp and call myFunction in the controller of my-list-comp? How should I do this I have no idea?